# React Excel Workbook build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating an excel report using this, https://github.com/ClearC2/react-excel-workbook, This is the code i am using to export excel file.

```
 <Workbook
      filename={excelsection}
      element={<Button label="Download Excel" icon="ui-icon-cloud-download"></Button>}
 >
      <Workbook.Sheet data={arr3} name="Sheet A">
           <Workbook.Column label="Student ID" value="customStudentId" />
           <Workbook.Column label={kc8}  />
      </Workbook.Sheet>
 </Workbook>
```

The problem is I can get the value of header `<Workbook.Column label={kc8}  />` in my localhost, but after building the project i don't get any value from that. What is wrong with the build?

Answer (score 1):

Every **Workbook.Column** should have **label** and **value**.

- **label** value is the title of the table in Excel
- **value** is the table contents (value gets from **data**)

You should write the second **Worksheet.Column** like this:

```
<Workbook.Column label="kc8" value="..."/>
```